# iOS 7 and xcode 5 framework issues

Tags: frameworks, ios7, xcode5

Using xcode 5 with my upgraded iOS 6 to iOS 7 app, I have run into issues with upgrading third party frameworks and adding third party frameworks which 'break' other seemingly unrelated frameworks. For example, I tried to upgrade the Crittercism framework which was already included in my project and it broke my Stackmob framework with the result that the project build failing because it couldn't find the Stackmob framework even though it was in the same location before the Crittercism upgrade. I had to remove the Stackmob framework first, then upgrade Crittercism, then reinstall the Stackmob framework, then the build succeeded. Another example, is when I tried to install the Parse framework. That broke my PushIOManager framework resulting in the project build failing since it was unable to find the PushIOManager framework even though it was in the same location as before I did the Parse installation. This is after doing clean and builds on the project. This does not seem to be happening with the built-in frameworks when I add them to the project. What's weird, is that I tried doing all this on an iOS 6 copy of the app using xcode 4.6 and everything worked fine, no issues whatsoever. I was just wondering if anyone else is running into similarly strange issues with their upgraded iOS 7 app and xcode 5. Or if this is just some weird stuff that's unique to my app.

Comment: it's most likely the 3rd party libraries that just need to be updated to iOS 7…there are different and new things added in 7 that were taken out in 6..

Comment: I'm having similar issues, but mainly about adding the same frameworks to a new project that didn't have them before (the existing frameworks seem to have migrated fine...)